# Android resize checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I created my own selector to the checkbox, but can't change the size of it. If I set layout_height from wrap_content to e.g. 20dp, the line height gets smaller but the size of the checkboxes stays resulting in overlapping each other. If I set       android:height="20dp" and    android:width="20dp" with the layout_height and width, nothing happens. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/cbon" />
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/cboff" />
</selector>


        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/multiple_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:checked="true"
            android:button="@drawable/productlists_custom_cb"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put

```
android:layout_width="20dip"
android:layout_height="20dip"
```

in your layout xml only. That works, but not the way you'd love to see it.
Why don't you apply your images as checkboxes and resize them to whatever size you want.

Comment: You mean I should resize the checkbox images to smaller in the image editor I created them? I did it and it works but I don't get why I cannot resize them in android.